# Flutter side drawer as a widget

Tags: dart, flutter, navigation-drawer

I am trying to implement side drawer as a widget in my flutter app

**home.dart**

```
import '../widgets/navigation_drawer_widget.dart'; //imported the nav drawer class from widgets directory

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          drawer: DrawerWidget(),
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Home'),
            bottom: TabBar(tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.access_time),
                text: 'Tab 1',
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                text: 'Tab 2',
              )
            ]),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(children: <Widget>[
            Tab1(),
            Tab2()
          ]),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

my drawer widget ** navigation_drawer_widget.dart** file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DrawerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: Text('Menu'),
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text('Home'),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.person),
          title: Text('My Profile'),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/profile');
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.school),
          title: Text('My Education'),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/education');
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

But when I click the nav hamburger icon it shows me something like this

[image]

As you can see the nav drawer becomes transparent and extends to the full width of the page. If I move the drawer code to the home page (instead of doing DrawerWidget() ) it will show the regular good ol nav drawer.

Any idea whats happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the `Column` in the `DrawerWidget` with a `Drawer` if you want default material design drawer.

From the doc:

> A drawer could be any Widget, but it’s often best to use the `Drawer` widget from the material library, which adheres to the Material Design spec.

https://flutter.io/cookbook/design/drawer/

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your `Drawer` as a `Widget` instead of a `Class` and then import inside your file.

```
Widget myDrawer = Drawer(
  child: ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    children: <Widget>[
      DrawerHeader(...),
      ListTile(...)
    ],
  ),
);
```

and then just:

```
import 'mydrawer.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(...),
      body: Container(...),
      drawer: myDrawer
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Container to change transparent drawer

Example:

```
 class DrawerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext contx) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.amber[600],
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          AppBar(automaticallyImplyLeading: false, title: Text('menu')),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(contx, '/home');
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.person),
            title: Text('My Profile'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(contx, '/profile');
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.school),
            title: Text('My Education'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(contx, '/education');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```